# How to deploy ONLY .EXE and custom .BPL files?

Tags: plugins, bpl, c++builder-2009

I would like to develop GUI application with plugins. The plugins contains VCL Forms which are inherited from Base Forms in the Plugin-Core library. The main application can select which plugin to load dynamically, and then which Form subclasses to display.

In the users side, I would like to deploy main **.EXE**, the Plugin-Core library, and many plugin libraries for different models. I could release new or modify existed plugin libraries to users to display new Forms for new devices without modifying the main ***.EXE*** and the Plugin-Core library.

The first version I developed uses DLL approach, namely both the Plugin-Core library and the plugins are in DLL form. Everything is just fine on the users side. However, in the developers side, the plugin DLL project can not be linked without Base Forms defined in the Plugin-Core DLL project. It means that the Base Forms are actually statically linked in each plugin DLL project, and if someday I modify the Base Forms and rebuild the Plugin-Core DLL project, I have to rebuild all plugin DLL projects and re-release plugin ***.DLL*** s to users, too.

After searching and asking in StackOverflow, I realized the limitation that VCL Forms can NOT be inherited across DLL boundary is due to RTTI conflict(?). The suggested solution is to modify the libraries from DLL to BPL form, which is the second version I developed. Everything is also fine except the following two:

1. The dynamic loaded Form from plugin BPL is separated from the main ***.EXE*** in Windows taskbar. It is not what I desired. The solution is that I enabled "Build with runtime packages" in the ***.EXE*** project.
2. After I enabled "Build with runtime packages" in the ***.EXE*** project, I have to release other .BPLs to the users, such as ***vcl.bpl*** and ***rtl.bpl***. This is not perfectly what I desired.

I would like to know that the above two issues can be resolved at the same time? In my thought, I could resolve both two issues if I:

1. Disable "Build with runtime packages" in ***.EXE*** project.
2. Enable "Build with runtime packages" in all ***.BPL*** projects.

In this way, the ***.EXE*** can run without ***vcl.bpl*** and ***rtl.bpl*** bundled, and the plugin ***.BPL*** s can be loaded successfully because the dependent units are already part of the main ***.EXE***? Am I correct? However, the "Build with runtime packages" checkbox is disabled in all ***.BPL*** project options. As a result I don't have a chance to check whether the solution works or not. I am sorry for the lengthy description and I can not attach picture due to company's Internet security policy.

Answer (score 1):

> The dynamic loaded Form from plugin BPL is separated from the main .EXE in Windows taskbar. It is not what I desired. The solution is that I enabled "Build with runtime packages" in the .EXE project.

After loading a BPL, pass the EXE's `Application.Handle` to the BPL and assign it to the BPL's own `Application.Handle` before it creates any Form instances.

Alternatively, on Windows 7+, you can have the EXE call `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()` to establish a App ID for its taskbar button.  Then each Form in the BPLs can use `SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow()` and `IPropertyStore.SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID)` to set the same App ID for their windows.  Multiple windows with the same App ID are grouped together under a single taskbar button.

See MSDN for more details: [Application User Model IDs (AppUserModelIDs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459.aspx)

> I would like to know that the above two issues can be resolved at the same time? In my thought, I could resolve both two issues if I:
>
> 1. Disable "Build with runtime packages" in .EXE project.
> 2. Enable "Build with runtime packages" in all .BPL projects.
>
> In this way, the .EXE can run without vcl.bpl and rtl.bpl bundled, and the plugin .BPL s can be loaded successfully because the dependent units are already part of the main .EXE? Am I correct?

No.  BPLs cannot use the EXE's built-in units like that.

If you disable "Build with Runtime Packages", the RTL/VCL units will be statically linked into the executable file.  The problem with doing that is multiple copies of a given unit cannot be loaded in memory at the same time, so you wouldn't be able to load multiple BPLs together (or even at all) if the same RTL/VCL units are statically linked into multiple BPLs, or even the EXE itself.

If you enable "Build with Runtime Packages", the executable file will be dependent on the RTL/VCL BPLs, which must then be deployed.

So, if your EXE and BPLs share common units, those units **must** be loaded via shared BPL(s) so only one copy of the units exist in memory.  There is no avoiding that when writing custom BPLs.  Which means at a *minimum* you usually have to deploy RTL.BPL if you are using basic RTL functionalities, and VCL.BPL for UIs.

Comment: Hi @Remy. Thanks a lot, again. 
1. "pass the EXE's Application.Handle to the BPL and assign it to the BPL's own Application.Handle"
==> This seems not working for VCL Forms from BPL. But this works for DLL. My first version development did this way.
2. My BPL project's "Build with rumtime packages" checkbox is disabled, and is unchecked. I guess which means rtl.bpl and vcl.bpl are statically linked into my BPLs. As a result, the only solution is to enable "Build with rumtime packages" in .EXE project to prevent multiple copies of VCL/BPL units as you suggested, right?